# GeckoFx print from URL rendered

Tags: c#, geckofx

Does geckoFx support @media print? When I send windows.print() from my URL it prints like a normal windows.print() without the scss format and the URL.

Im using Geckofx45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem was that Geckofx was printing header and footer by default. If anyone ever comes into the same problem try this:

```
GeckoPreferences.User["print.print_footerright"] = "";
```

You can find the rest on your own about:config or http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries .